# Android YouTube Player API + compatlib

Tags: android, youtube-api

Since the [Android YouTube Player API](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/12/no-webview-required-with-native-youtube.html) requires activities to extend [YouTubeBaseActivity](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeBaseActivity), it's difficult to support anything but the full screen player or YouTube intents with [compatlib](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

Is it possible to use an embedded [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) or [YouTubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) yet still be backwards compatible with FroYo (i.e. using compatlib or ActionBarSherlock)?

Comment: Have you looked at the examples? They have examples for both use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Sample application](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications), you'll find that it uses the compatibility library.

Comment: Ah, YouTubePlayerSupportFragment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No need to extend **YouTubeBaseActivity**. Instead, you can use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment to achieve the same. By doing this you can able to use compatlibs.

Here is the example:

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {


private  YouTubePlayer mYouTubePlayer;
private final String VIDEO_CODE="repalce with video code";
private final String API_KEY="replace with your api key ";
private  YouTubePlayerSupportFragment mYouTubePlayerSupportFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    youTubePlayerSetup();
}

private void youTubePlayerSetup(){

    mYouTubePlayerSupportFragment =
            (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);
    mYouTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    if (!b) {
        mYouTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
        mYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(VIDEO_CODE);
}}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}}
```

And in your {layout}.xml replace YoutubePlayerView with the a fragment.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.HomeScreen">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```